# Separating data in array where duplicates are present using foreach loop in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have a database table with one column that will be options and another column that respresents the option values for that option. Example:

```
Options:   Option Values
Color   -  Red
Color   -  Blue
Size    -  Large
Size    -  Small
```

How do I loop through the data to where I can populate a select box where the options are grouped like:

```
Color:
     Red
     Blue

Size:
     Large
     Small
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display `<select>` box for each, I would do something like the following :-

( being sure to `ORDER BY 'Options'` or similar depending on your database )

```
$previous_option = "";
$count = 0;
foreach($data as $row){
    if($row['options'] != $previous_option){
        if($count>0){
            echo '</select>'.$row['options'].': <select name="'.$row['options'].'">';
        } else {
            echo $row['options'].': <select name="'.$row['options'].'">';
        }
    }
    echo '<option>'.$row['value'].'</option>';
    $count++;
    $previous_option = $row['options'];
}
```

- `$data` = your database result.
- `$row['options']` = database column 'options'.
- `$row['value']` = database column 'options values'
- `$previous_option` = used for option "grouping"
- `$count` = used for tracking first iteration

Answer (score 0):

Loop over each row, and use PHP's [] array operator and your option name as a key to a multi-dimensional array.

```
foreach($yourRows as $data) {
  if (!isset($options[$data['option']])) {
    $options[$data['option']] = array();
  }
  $options[$data['option']][] = $data['value'];
}
```

This will make a two-dimensional array, where the first level is associative, keyed on the option names, and each of those keys contains a numerically-indexed array of that option's values.

The resulting array will look it was created like this:

```
$options = array(
  "color" => array("red", "blue"),
  "size"  => array("small", "large")
);
```

then iterate like this over the options as needed:

```
echo '<select name="options"  multiple="multiple">';
foreach($options as $option_type => $available_options) {
  printf('<optgroup label="%s">', $option_type);
  foreach($available_options as $avail) 
    printf('<option value="%s">%s</option>', $avail, $avail);
  echo '</optgroup>';
} 
echo '</select>';
```

This will create a select that renders like this in Safari (I selected red and large):

[image]

Comment: Will the options name be treated as one individual option or will the options name be duplicated with the values below?

Comment: The string "options" will not occur in the final array (see edit). You can then iterate the available colors with something like: `foreach($options['color'] as $color)`

Comment: Just noticed the part about grouping the select in your Question. You need the <optgroup> tag; which is demonstrated in my answer.

Comment: Let me see if this still applies to the code you posted. I want each option by itself as a label of sorts then, the option values will be in a select box below each option label. Will the code you posted do what I am looking for or, am I really in need of some serious sleep?

Comment: I modified the answer a bit (added multiple to the select) and added a screenshot from my Safari of what the HTML this produces will look like.